# refinerycms not working when adding page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinerycms

I'm getting this error when trying to add a new page from the dashboard with refinerycms

SQLite3::ConstraintException: refinery_page_translations.refinery_page_id may not be NULL: INSERT INTO "refinery_page_translations" ("created_at", "custom_slug", "locale", "menu_title", "refinery_page_id", "slug", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

with the next gemfile

gem 'rails', '3.2.14'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails','~> 2.3.0'

gem 'refinerycms', '~> 2.1.0'

Comment: Can you run rake `db:seed` bundling with refinerycms without errors?

Comment: Experiencing the same thing. I've just tried a `rake db:seed` with similar errors. `SQLite3::ConstraintException: refinery_page_translations.refinery_page_id may not be NULL:.....`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on an answer I found at https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/issues/2450, add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'globalize3', '0.3.0'
```

and run

```
bundle install
```

if this fails you may need to do as the error output suggests, and run

```
bundle update globalize3
```

You may need to delete and recreate your databases via

```
$ rm db\*.sqlite3
$ rake db:migrate db:seed
```

This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: changing the globalize gem to 0.3.0 fix the problem